# Writing a string to text file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text-files, activexobject

We are attempting to save a URL stored in a string to a text file, but we can't seem to get it to work. It will not save into the file, although our testing shows that the function is actually running when it should be.

The code for this is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="instagramclick()">Login to instagram</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Test Button</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello World");
}

function instagramclick(){
    alert("button clicked");
    window.location.href = "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=8a612cd650344523808233c0468c80ed&redirect_uri=http://u-ahmed.github.io/HookedUp/instagram.html&response_type=token";
}

function WriteDemo(link)
{
 var fso, f, r;
 var ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2;
 fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
 f = fso.OpenTextFile("database.txt", ForWriting, true);
 f.Write(link);
 f.Close();
 r = f.ReadLine();
return(r);
}

window.onload = function writedamnyou(){
var token = window.location.href.substring(62);
if (token != ""){
    // document.write(token);
    var link = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=" + token;
    // w = window.open('database.txt')
    WriteDemo(link);
  // document.write(stuff);


}
};

</script>
<p id="no"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which browser are you testing?

Comment: This is being run in chrome.

Comment: chrome doesn't support activex anymore, use internet explorer instead. And if you'll use your app in chrome, this method is not going to help you, try native messaging